# Does a principal act upon a target, or does an agent act upon a patient?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, identifier-choice

In a software application, I have an access model that contains a set of data structures, each describing how a given entity may or may not act upon another given entity.  An "entity" is a person, a thing, or a group of people and/or things.

- **Alice** *may* read mail sent to **Bob**.
- **Carol** *may not* send messages to **residents of Danville**.
- **Everyone** *may* connect to **the public server**.

  <sup>(These are contrived examples only.  I am not writing a mail server.)</sup>

In each sentence above, we have:

- an actor (Alice, Carol, everyone),
- a permission (may, may not),
- an action (read mail, send messages, connect), and
- an object, either direct or indirect (Bob, residents of Danville, the public server).

A hallmark of quality, maintainable software code is clarity—that is, it should not only be easy to understand, but the intentions should be clear.  An important facet of this goal is that the names of things should make their functions obvious.  They should also be concise, because long, overly descriptive names are not only more effort to type, but also more effort to read.

What's more, the parlance must cater to the particular language quirks that are the jargon of the industry.  For example, the word "object" would be a poor choice here, because that word has an [industry-specific meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science)) that would render it rather ambiguous in this context.

I'm therefore struggling with succinct names for the person or other entity who performs an action and for the person or other entity who/which is the recipient of said action.

The original terms I came up with were **principal**, as in "a chief actor or performer", and **target**, as in "one to be influenced or changed by an action or event."  It occurs to me, however, that the linguistic terms that most closely represent the concepts are **agent** and **patient**.

Going back to the subject of clarity, though, I'm not sure that these uses for "agent" and "patient" would be immediately understood by software developers, or indeed by most people without a background in linguistics.  I wonder, then, if the original words are clearer, and if perhaps there exists another pair of terms that would be an even better choices.

Comment: so you want names for the one who performs the action and on whom it impacts

Comment: I don't like *patient*, and I don't like *principal*. What's wrong with an *agent* acting on a *target*?

Comment: If your developers do not understand what an agent is, it think it is a good thing they learn it :) It is very commonly used in IT. On the other hand, _patient_ will be understood as someone who is ill and needs a _doctor_, not  an agent.

Comment: What about "acting entity" and "entity acted upon"?

Comment: vickyace: yes, Peter Shor, oerkelens: I don't care for "patient" either, as its medical use is much more well known.  I also, however, don't care much for "agent", though, because call center employees are often called "agents".  Besides, to me, "agent" implies an individual, whereas the entity granted permission may be more abstract (e.g., a group).  rogermue, those terms are precise, but not concise.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming, including naming programming variables/classes.

Comment: FWIW, the quickest answer I could think of was "doer" and "deed". They sound funny but they more or less convey the meaning desired. (You could also use actor/action... but I noticed you used those words in your post. What was wrong with them?)

Comment: @MrHen:  The actor/doer/agent/principal is indeed something I'd like to name, and each of these is more or less accurate, to some degree or another.  The level of clarity varies pretty widely.  The deed or action is not something I was asking about, as I think "action" is both accurate and clear.  The other term I'm struggling on is name of the patient/target/object (direct or indirect).  This latter term is best described as the entity that is acted upon.